# Create wordpress Widget multiple instances

Tags: php, plugins, widget, wordpress

I've created a wordpress little widget (a form with 2 fields) and display it on the back office..

Everything works fine, And I can using it to create only one record and display it in the front, but what I really want to do is to be able to create many records from the back-office using it (like posts) and display them to the front office of the website.

> **Published Records on the front-office : (what I want)**

```
Record1               |     Record2               |     Record3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title:    Title1      |     Title:    Title2      |     Title:    Title3
Price:    Price1      |     Price:    Price2      |     Price:    Price3
```

> **Published Record on the front-office : (what I actually Have)**

```
Record               
----------------------
Title:    Title      
Price:    Price
```

Here's my code :

```
class wp_ikbal extends WP_Widget {

    // constructor
    function wp_ikbal() {
        parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = __('Ikbal Widget', 'wp_ikbal') );
    }

    // widget form creation
    function form($instance) {  
        // Check values
        if( $instance) {
            $Title = esc_attr($instance['text']);
            $Price = esc_textarea($instance['textarea']);
        } else {
            $Title = '';
            $Price = '';
        }
        ?>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('Title'); ?>"><?php _e('Nom Produit:', 'wp_ikbal'); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('Title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('Title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $Title; ?>" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('Price'); ?>"><?php _e('Price:', 'wp_ikbal'); ?></label>
            <textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('Price'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('Price'); ?>"><?php echo $Price; ?></textarea>
        </p>
        <?php
    }

    // widget update
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        // Fields
        $instance['Title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['Title']);
        $instance['Price'] = strip_tags($new_instance['Price']);
        return $instance;
    }

    // widget display
    function widget($args, $instance) {
        extract( $args );
        // these are the widget options
        $text = $instance['Title'];
        $textarea = $instance['Price'];
        echo $before_widget;
        // Display the widget
        echo '<div class="widget-text wp_widget_plugin_box">';

        // Check if text is set
        if( $Title ) {
            echo '<p class="wp_widget_plugin_text">'.$Title.'</p>';
        }

        // Check if textarea is set
        if( $Price ) {
            echo '<p class="wp_widget_plugin_textarea">'.$Price.'</p>';
        }

        echo '</div>';
        echo $after_widget;
    }
}

// register widget
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("wp_ikbal");'));
```

How can I do this ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need *Repeatable Fields*, the answer here would be verbatim of [this one in WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/89166). Basically:

1. In the Widget constructor add an [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) to load the needed jQuery (or you can put it inline in `form()`).
2. In `form()` add the markup to have a "template" for the inputs and that's used by jQuery to duplicate the fields.
3. In `update()`, iterate through the posted fields and save accordingly.

Resources:

- [Create more Meta Boxes as needed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/19852/12615) - WPSE Q&A
- [Custom Meta Boxes: Store two values in one repeatable field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/52383) - WPSE Q&A
- [Repeatable Custom Fields in a Metabox](https://gist.github.com/1593065) - Gist
- [Repeatable Custom Fields in a Metabox](https://gist.github.com/2057532) - Another Gist. This one has the code to sort the fields.

PS: you'll probably find that jQuery don't work when the Widget is firstly dropped into a sidebar. The solution is [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/119176).